# Can I update the UI during PDF creation?

Tags: ios, multithreading, pdf-generation, background-process

I'm trying to create a multipage PDF for the QuickLook framework to print but am unable to update the UI while creating it (I want the user to get a countdown of how many pages remain). The following code is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do with the thread sleep stuff standing in for code which takes a while to render.

```
- (void) testPDF
{
    CGRect pageSize = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 595.28, 841.89);

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile([self filePath], pageSize, nil);
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

        for( int y = 0; y < 5; y++ )    {
            self.pageLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", y];

            [[UIColor grayColor] set];
            [@"test string" drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, y*20) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];

            NSDate *future = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 1.0];
            [NSThread sleepUntilDate:future];
        }
    }
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}
```

As it stands my code renders the PDF but doesn't update the IBOutlet 'pageLabel', any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you tried running this on a background thread and sending updates for the UI back to the main thread.

Comment: Thanks Wain, got the answer from @bobnoble below - it was indeed just my lame knowledge of threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the PDF creation on a background thread, but update the UI on the main (aka UI) thread. Once the PDF creation is complete, call the method (in this case `presentPDF`) to present the PDF to the user, making sure to switch to the main thread before doing so.  For example:

```
-(void)presentPDF{

    // Make sure this runs on the main (UI) thread
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        //Insert code to present the PDF...

    });
}

- (void) testPDF
{

    // Run on background thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        CGRect pageSize = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 595.28, 841.89);

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile([self filePath], pageSize, nil);
        {
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

            for( int y = 0; y < 5; y++ ){

                // Make sure this runs on the main (UI) thread
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    self.pageLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", y];

                });

                [[UIColor grayColor] set];
                [@"test string" drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, y*20) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];

                NSDate *future = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 1.0];
                [NSThread sleepUntilDate:future];
            }
        }
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

        [self presentPDF];
    });
}
```

Comment: so the drawAtPoint method call needs to be made on the main thread even though it is writing to the PDF rather than the screen?

Comment: @amergin - sorry, no. The setting of `self.pageLabel.text` needs to be done on the main thread. I fixed the code.